# How can gods hide themselves from other god's gaze?

Tags: greek, athena, iliad

I know of Hades with his Helm of Darkness. I know that Athena gave a Helm of Darkness to the hero Perseus and later used it (or another) herself in the Iliad to hid from Ares. Another point in the Iliad is with Zeus hiding himself and Hera in a cloud so the other gods don't see them making love.

What other ways do the gods hide themselves?